# How do I use a variable in Js controller to my HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I want to validate my form with ng-disable.

So my function will check if the ID the user entered is correct.
Also I will have to check my form if all the inputs are filled up.

This is my Function:

```
vm.validateid = function(){
    console.log('here');
    var objvar = {
        'id': vm.data.referalid,
        'referral2': true,
    };

    $http.post(ConfigCnst.restUrl,objvar).then(function(res) {
        if (res.data.status !== true) {   

             alert('Invalid ID');
             vm.data.referalName = 'Invalid ID';
             vlid = res.data.status;
             console.log(vlid);

        } else {

            alert('ID Validated');
            vm.data.referalName = JSON.stringify(res.data.data.name);
            vlid = res.data.status;
            console.log(vlid);
        }

    });
}
```

I want to take `vlid`. It will either contain true or false.

This is my ng-disable:

```
 <button ng-disabled="registerForm.$invalid" 
         ng-click="register.submit()"  
         class="button button-block button-positive">Confirm</button>
```

I want to check both `registerForm` and `vlid` as both false.
Is there a way to reference my `vlid` from my controller?

Comment: `all are filled up` ... if use validation attributes/directives form will stay `$invalid=true` until requirements are matched on all fields and each field becomes `$valid=true`. In other words you shouldn't need to check again in client....but always revalidate at server

Comment: yea, so once I have my form valid, i also need to get my ID to be valid. my function validates my ID, but then i dont know how to add that status(valid ID) to the form...

Comment: solutions below in answers manage the id flag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not being able to see where/how your controller is defined makes this a bit more difficult, but yes, you can access scope variables from a controller. 
So, there are two likely ways your controller might be defined:
**Using ControllerAs:**
You would have `myController as someName` in your html.
You can then pass `someName.vlid` to your function, and then bind this to `res.data.status`
**Binding to $scope:**
In your controller, you would have a parameter `$scope`
You can then use `$scope.vlid` in your controller or `ng-model='vlid'` in your html, pass that to your function, and treat it in the same way.
If you've defined that function in your controller, you can use `ng-model='vlid'` or `ng-model='someName.vlid'` depending on the way your controller is defined.

Comment: fairly clear OP is using controllerAs syntax...is using `vm` as `this`

Answer (score 2):

Set the variable `vlid`  to a `$scope` variable in your controller(`$scope.vlid=vlid`). Then you can access it in your html view. You need to update `ng-disabled` expression to include condition for `vlid`.

```
<button ng-disabled="registerForm.$invalid && !vlid" ng-click="register.submit()"  class="button button-block button-positive">Confirm </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can refer vlid using $scope.

```
vm.validateid = function() {
  console.log('here');
  var objvar = {
    'id': vm.data.referalid,
    'referral2': true,
  };
  $http.post(ConfigCnst.restUrl, objvar).then(function(res) {
    if (res.data.status !== true) {

      alert('Invalid ID');
      vm.data.referalName = 'Invalid ID';
      vlid = res.data.status;
      $scope.vlid_status = res.data.staus;
      console.log(vlid);
    } else {

      alert('ID Validated');
      vm.data.referalName = JSON.stringify(res.data.data.name);
      vlid = res.data.status;
      $scope.vlid_status = res.data.staus;

      console.log(vlid);
    }

  });
}
```

HTML

```
<button ng-disabled="registerForm.$invalid && vlid_status === false" ng-click="register.submit()"  class="button button-block button-positive">Confirm </button>
```